# Compare and get greatest date and related fields

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to using VBA for Excel and need to develop some code that will retrieve a person's greatest Exam dates and related fields (Exam date, Exam Check Date, Exam Induration) and output to another tab called EXAMCI.

Because of data integrity issues with the date input file, In some instances Exam Date (Column D) will be greater than 2nd Exam Date (Column H), and vice versa; there will be some instances when the 2nd Exam Date (Column H) is greater than the first Exam date (Column D).

Here is some sample data from the file (Columns are A - K, Left to Right):

```
Userid  Employee Name   DOB             Exam Date       Exam Check Date Exam Induration Exam Negative   2nd Exam Date   2nd Exam Check Date 2nd Exam Induration 2nd Exam Negative
1234    John Smith      1/1/01          5/22/17         5/24/17         0               Yes             12/6/17         12/8/17             0                   Yes
6481    Jill Son        2/2/02          11/18/15        11/21/15        0               Yes             2/23/17         2/26/17             0                   Yes
3271    Cathy John      3/3/03          7/17/17         7/19/17         0               Yes             6/15/16         6/17/16             0                   Yes
```

In the above example data you can see that the first Exam Date is greater than then 2nd Exam Date for John Smith and Cathy John, however the 2nd Exam Date is greater than the first Exam Date for Jill Son.

What I want the program to do is check each row to see whether Exam Date or 2nd Exam Date is the greatest (of the two) and then output Userid, Employee Name, DOB, and either the (Exam Date, Check Date, and Exam Induration) or the (2nd Exam Date, 2nd Exam Check Date, and 2nd Exam Induration) -- depending on which associated date was greater.

So in the example John Smith and Jill Son, I would want to output on the tab EXAMCI the following data (column labels can remain the same, e.g. no need to distinguish between Exam Date and 2nd Exam Date:)

```
Userid     Employee Name    DOB       Exam Date     Exam Check Date    Exam Induration
1234       John Smith       1/1/01    5/22/17       5/24/17            0
3271       Jill Son         3/3/03    2/23/17       2/26/17            0
```

Please let me know if the requirement is not clear, thanks for any feedback!

**EDIT:**

Here is the code I am attempting to add into this already existing program, function is called **Examdate**:

Public lstrow As Long, strDate As Variant, stredate As Variant

```
Sub importbuild()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Define last row of exported data
lstrow = Worksheets("Data").Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Worksheets("Data").Cells.Replace what:="=", Replacement:="", _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

'Run function to build import file for Hepatitis Immunizations
Call HepLoad("O", "P", "HB1")
Call HepLoad("Q", "R", "HB2")
Call HepLoad("S", "T", "HB3")
Call HepLoad("U", "V", "HB1")
Call HepLoad("W", "X", "HB2")
Call HepLoad("Y", "NA", "HB3")
'Run function for Hepatitis Series Completed
Call HepSeries("Z", "AA")
'Run function for Titers
Call Titer("AB", "AC", "HT")
Call Titer("AD", "AE", "RT")
Call Titer("AF", "AG", "UT")
Call Titer("AH", "AI", "VT")
'Run functions for Varicella Immunizations
Call DateOnlyLoad("AJ", "AK", "VAR1")
Call DateOnlyLoad("AL", "NA", "VAR2")
'Run function for Tetanus Immunizations
Call TetanusLoad("AM", "AN")
'Run function for MMR Immunizations
Call DateOnlyLoad("AO", "AP", "MMR1")
Call DateOnlyLoad("AQ", "NA", "MMR2")
'Call BCGLoad("BA", "NA", "BCG")
Call Examdate

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

*(Other functions omitted)*

```
Function Examdate()

Dim Exam_1_Date As Variant
Dim Exam_2_Date As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long

j = Worksheets("PPDCI").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
For i = 2 To lstrow

Exam_1_Date = Worksheets("Data").Range("AW" & i)
Exam_2_Date = Worksheets("Data").Range("BA" & i)

If Exam_1_Date > Exam_2_Date Then
   Worksheets("PPDCI").Range("A" & j & ":C" & j).Value = 
Worksheets("Data").Range("F" & i & ":H" & i).Value
   Worksheets("PPDCI").Range("F" & j).Value = Exam_1_Date
Else
    If Exam_1_Date < Exam_2_Date Then
    Worksheets("PPDCI").Range("A" & j & ":C" & j).Value = 
Worksheets("Data").Range("F" & i & ":H" & i).Value
    Worksheets("PPDCI").Range("F" & j).Value = Exam_2_Date
    End If
Worksheets("PPDCI").Range("F" & j).Value = "CAN NOT DETERMINE"
End If

Next i

End Function
```

When I attempt to run the macro, I get an "Object required" error. Do I need to specify the variables up where the function is being called? Also does the logic appear to be correct?

Comment: you could use a helper column with a simple formula to determine if first or second date is grater `=IF(D:D>H:H,1,2)` so it outputs a 1 if the first is greater and a 2 if the second. Then use filers to filter for 1 or 2 in this helper column. Of course you could copy the filtered data to another sheet easily. • Because this is no free code writing service please start on your own and then come back with your code and tell where you got stuck or errors.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I edited the post to include my code.

Comment: Remove the `Set` from `Set Exam_1_Date`. The variable is of type date which is just a value not an object. `Set` is only needed for objects. Also make sure you use `Option Explicit` and define all your variables correctly. Eg. `Dim i As Long`. Also `k` and `j` seem not to be defined so they are `0` which makes `Range("F" & k)` fail because there is no row `0`.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I made changes and removed Set from the variables. It runs however it does not return the expected data. It is returning only 1 record duplicated on 2 rows. I am expecting much more data to be returned...

Comment: because you didn't increase `j`. You need a `j = j + 1` everytime data is added otherwise it overwrites always into the same row.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Ok I added j = j + 1 just above the End If clause. Now I am getting data returned, however all of it is resulting in the "CAN NOT DETERMINE" logic, when I know that there are dates populated in columns AW and BA.  Thoughts?  Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use an `If … ElseIf … Else … End If` statement and increase `j`.

```
For i = 2 To lstrow
    Exam_1_Date = Worksheets("Data").Range("AW" & i)
    Exam_2_Date = Worksheets("Data").Range("BA" & i)

    If Exam_1_Date > Exam_2_Date Then
        Worksheets("PPDCI").Range("A" & j & ":C" & j).Value = Worksheets("Data").Range("F" & i & ":H" & i).Value
        Worksheets("PPDCI").Range("F" & j).Value = Exam_1_Date
    ElseIf Exam_1_Date < Exam_2_Date Then
        Worksheets("PPDCI").Range("A" & j & ":C" & j).Value = Worksheets("Data").Range("F" & i & ":H" & i).Value
        Worksheets("PPDCI").Range("F" & j).Value = Exam_2_Date
    Else
        Worksheets("PPDCI").Range("F" & j).Value = "CAN NOT DETERMINE"
    End If
    j = j + 1
Next i
```

Comment: @Peh Thanks, I am now getting data returned with dates, however I noticed that I have several duplicate rows for my records. For example, one person has 4 rows, 3 of which have the "CAN NOT DETERMINE", the 4th rows contains the ExamDate. Ideas why this is occuring?

Comment: @nick no because I don't know how your data looks like. I suggest to go through your code step by step (with F8) and debug what happens (check variable values and which row you are every step).

Comment: @Peh thanks, just wasn't sure if I needed to change anything in the IF statement to be something like Exam_1_Date.Value > Exam_2_Date.Value (As opposed to just Exam_1_Date > Exam_2_Date.

Comment: @Nick just another idea: Remove the last `Else` block with the `CAN NOT DETERMINE` completely and move the `j = j + 1` within the first `If` AND the `ElseIf` and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: @Peh thanks again, the issue was that I had run the macro several times and each time it kept replicating on the same worksheet, creating the duplicates. Everything looks good now! This was a great exercise for me to get a taste of VBA! Thanks again for your help!